# contar años repetidos en una tabla

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

espero que me puedan ayudar al igual que en mis otras preguntas.

quiero contar los años de una tabla en una consulta SQL, es decir que me muestre cuantas veces se repite el año 2018, 2019, 2020... pero en mi campo fecha la fecha se muestra de la siguiente manera AAAA-MM-DD. adjunto una imagen de mi tabla.

[image: Imagen de referencia de mi tabla]

espero me puedan entender lo que necesito. quedo atento a sus comentarios y muchas gracias...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria algo así

```
select year(fecha), count(*) from miTabla
group by year(fecha).

year(fecha) | count(*)
2018        | 2
2019        | 2
```

Te dejo un link para que le des un vistazo

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec8bf96/5

Espero y te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Saludos puedes hacer algo como esto:

Teniendo la siguiente tabla de ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE miTabla (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre varchar(255),
    curso varchar(255),
    fecha date,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
insert into miTabla (nombre, curso, fecha)
values('Diego', 'Decimo A', '2019-01-06');
insert into miTabla (nombre, curso, fecha)
values('Fernando', 'Decimo B', '2019-02-06');
insert into miTabla (nombre, curso, fecha)
values('Gabriela', 'Octavo A', '2018-01-01');
insert into miTabla (nombre, curso, fecha)
values('Tamara', 'Octavo B', '2018-02-01');
```

mi query será:

```
select count(id) from miTabla where YEAR(fecha)=2019
```

Resultado:

```
2
```

**Explicación**
Lo que se hace es contar un campo en este caso **id** luego mediante un **where** 
selecciono solo las fechas que coincidan con el año deseado en esta caso 2019.

como mis fechas serán algo así:

```
2019-01-06
```

Se debe obtener solo el año  con [YEAR](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp)

Resultado: [Resultado query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32a662/2)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!